# ldap_add(): Add: Constraint violation

Tags: php, ldap, apacheds

I am learning how to perform CRUD operations on a LDAP directory and using ApacheDS for the purpose.I am trying to add a new user but keep getting the following warning:

```
Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Constraint violation
```

Here's the php code I am using:

```
<?php
function ldap_add_user($user)
{
    include('ldap_config.php');
    include('ldap_admin.php');

    $connect = ldap_connect($host, $port);

    if ($connect) 
    {   
        ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        $bind = ldap_bind($connect,$username,$password); 

        $info['uid'] =  $user['mail_id'];
        $info['userPassword'] = $user['password'];
        $info['cn'] =  $user['firstname'].' '.$user['lastname'];
        $info['sn'] =  $user['lastname'];
        $info['objectClass'][3] = "inetOrgPerson";
        $info['objectClass'][2] = "organizationalPerson";
        $info['objectClass'][1] = "person";
        $info['objectClass'][0] = "top";
        $dn="uid=".$user['mail_id'].", ou=auth_users, o=mycompany";

        $r = ldap_add($connect,$dn,$info);
        ldap_close($connect);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {   
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

And,the interesting thing is that the above code works just fine when I use a numeric password for the $user['password'], but when I pass alphanumeric or non-numeric passwords I get the warning mentioned above.

Comment: LDAP returns error 19 when you attempt to add an attribute value that doesn't meet the size limitations, or when you attempt to add a 2nd value to an attribute that only allows one value to be present.

Comment: What worked for me was changing the attribute ads-pwdcheckquality from 2 to 0.I didn't get much time to look into why exactly it works but I  believe it relaxes the default criteria set on constraints for userPassword attribute.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question @user3739870, I've got the same problem. Most preferably I would like to choose a safe password, anyone got a solution for this? If not, where did you change the "ads-pwdcheckquality" attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache Directory Studio then right click on connection, select "Open Configuration" and navigate to "Password Policies" tab. You will see "Check Quality" option on right side.Turn it to "Disabled".